# Importing a CSV, reshaping a variable's array for logistic regression

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, regression, reshape

I hope that everybody is staying safe amid the COVID-19 pandemic. I am new to Python and have a quick question about importing data from a CSV into Python for conducting a simple logistic regression analysis where the dependent variable is binary, and the independent variable is continuous.

I imported a CSV file, then wished to use one variable (Active) as the independent variable and another variable (Smoke) as the response variable. I am able to load the CSV file into Python but each time I try to generate a logistic regression model to predict Smoke from Exercise, I get an error that Exercise has to be reshaped into one column (two dimensional), as it is currently one dimensional.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
data = pd.read_csv('Pulse.csv') # Read the data from the CSV file
x = data['Active'] # Load the values from Exercise into the independent variable
x = np.array.reshape(-1,1)
y = data['Smoke'] # The dependent variable is set as Smoke
```

I keep receiving the following error message:

> ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
>   array=[ 97.  82.  88. 106.  78. 109.  66.  68. 100.  70.  98. 140. 105.  84.
>    134. 117. 100. 108.  76.  86. 110.  65.  85.  80.  87. 133. 125.  61.
>    117.  90. 110.  68. 102.  67. 112.  86.  85.  66.  73.  85. 110.  97.
>     93.  86.  80.  96.  74. 124.  78.  93.  80.  80.  92.  69.  82.  88.
>     74.  74.  75. 120. 105. 104.  99. 113.  67. 125. 133.  98.  80.  91.
>     76.  78.  94. 150.  92.  96.  68.  82. 102.  69.  65.  84.  86.  84.
>    116.  88.  65. 101.  89. 128.  68.  90.  80.  80.  98.  90.  82.  97.
>     90.  98.  88.  94.  92.  96.  80.  66. 110.  87.  88.  94.  96.  89.
>     74. 111.  81.  98.  99.  65.  95. 127.  76. 102.  88. 125.  72.  76.
>    112.  69. 101.  72. 112.  81.  90.  96.  66. 114.  71.  75. 102. 138.
>     85.  80. 107. 119.  98.  95.  95.  76.  96. 102.  82.  99.  80.  83.
>    102. 102. 106.  79.  80.  79. 110. 144.  80.  97.  60.  80. 108. 107.
>     51.  68.  80.  80.  60.  64.  87. 110. 110.  82. 154. 139.  86.  95.
>    112. 120.  79.  64.  84.  65.  60.  79.  79.  70.  75. 107.  78.  74.
>     80. 121. 120.  96.  75. 106.  88.  91.  98.  63.  95.  85.  83.  92.
>     81.  89. 103. 110.  78. 122. 122.  71.  65.  92.  93.  88.  90.  56.
>     95.  83.  97. 105.  82. 102.  87.  81.].
>   Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

**Below is the entire, updated code with errors (04/12/2020):**
*I was unable to enter the error log into this document so I have copied and pasted it into this public Google Document: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vtrj6Znv54FJ4Zvv211TQvvCN6Ac5LDaOfvHicQn0nU/edit?usp=sharing

Also, here is the CSV file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g_-vPNklxRn_3nlNPsR-IOflLfXSzFb1/view?usp=sharing

```
scikit-learn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
data = pd.read_csv('Pulse.csv')
x = data['Active']
y = data['Smoke']
lr = LogisticRegression().fit(x.values.reshape(-1,1), y)
p_pred = lr.predict_proba(x.values)
y_pred = lr.predict(x.values)
score_ = lr.score(x.values,y.values)
conf_m = confusion_matrix(y.values,y_pred.values)
report = classification_report(y.values,y_pred.values)
confusion_matrix(y, lr.predict(x))    
cm = confusion_matrix(y, lr.predict(x))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (8,8))
ax.imshow(cm)
ax.grid(False)
ax.xaxis.set(ticks=(0,1), ticklabels = ('Predicted 0s', 'Predicted 1s'))
ax.yaxis.set(ticks=(0,1), ticklabels = ('Actual 0s', 'Actual 1s'))
ax.set_ylim(1.5, -0.5)
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        ax.text(j,i,cm[i,j],ha='center',va='center',color='red', size='45')
plt.show()
print(classification_report(y,model.predict(x)))
```

Comment: Try without this line `x = np.array.reshape(-1,1)`

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried it but the result was the same: "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead."

Comment: Can you add complete code which also includes the model fitting part?

Comment: Dear ManojK, thank you for your patience and copied support. I have updated this question with the entire code at my disposal, and I also copied and pasted the error log (which was not accepted here when I tried to submit it) into a Google Document. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
data = pd.read_csv('Pulse.csv')
x = pd.DataFrame(data['Smoke'])
y = data['Smoke']
lr = LogisticRegression()
lr.fit(x,y)
p_pred = lr.predict_proba(x)
y_pred = lr.predict(x)
score_ = lr.score(x,y)
conf_m = confusion_matrix(y,y_pred)
report = classification_report(y,y_pred)

print(score_)
0.8836206896551724

print(conf_m)
[[204   2]
 [ 25   1]]
```

Comment: Dear ManojK, many thanks for your patience and continued support... Unfortunately I was unable to get it to work. Here is a public link to the PDF: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_1FUHuLWh2KsxjbTXAdlx4lZHxPcrHEc/view?usp=sharing and here is the CSV file: http://www.stat2.org/datasets/Pulse.csv Sincerely, ciel_azzuro

Comment: See my updated code, it is working fine now, just changed this line: `x = pd.DataFrame(data['Smoke'])` it was giving errors as `x` was a `Series` now it is converted to a `DataFrame`.

Comment: I am immensely grateful for your valuable time and insight. The output of the analyses matched with that of another computational software (SPSS). Thank you.

Comment: I have just clicked the green check. If there is any further action, please let me know.

Comment: Dear ManojK, I just wanted to let you know that I have been referencing this page for your suggestion for future logistic regression models and your suggestion continues to be immensely useful. Thanks again.

Comment: Great, please let me know if you have any more questions.

Comment: Would you by chance have any experience with simple logistic regression  in Statsmodels? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61560569/simple-logistic-regression-with-statsmodels-adding-an-intercept-and-visualizing

Comment: I have answered on the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

data = pd.read_csv('Pulse.csv') # Read the data from the CSV file
x = data['Active'] # Load the values from Exercise into the independent variable
y = data['Smoke'] # The dependent variable is set as Smoke

lr = LogisticRegression().fit(x.values.reshape(-1,1), y)
```

Comment: Thank you. After entering the provided command, I received the following error:    `p_pred = lr.predict_proba(x)
y_pred = lr.predict(x)
score_ = lr.score(x,y)
conf_m = confusion_matrix(y,y_pred)
report = classification_report(y,y_pred)`

Comment: that isn't error, is a code.  Note that you must use x.values.reshape(-1,1) instead x

Comment: Dear Cristian, many thanks for the continued support. I tried your suggestion but was unable to circumvent the error. I have updated this question with the entire code, as well as the error log that is generated after trying to run it. Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you.