# Simple logistic regression with Statsmodels: Adding an intercept and visualizing the logistic regression equation

Tags: data-visualization, linear-regression, constants, statsmodels, traceback

Using Statsmodels, I am trying to generate a simple logistic regression model to predict whether a person smokes or not (Smoke) based on their height (Hgt).

I have a feeling that an intercept needs to be included into the logistic regression model but I am not sure how to implement one using the add_constant() function. Also, I am unsure why the error below is generated.

This is the dataset, Pulse.CSV: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FdUK9p4Dub4NXsc-zHrYI-AGEEBkX98V/view?usp=sharing

The full code and output are in this PDF file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kHlrAjiU7QvFXF2a7tlTSFPgfpq9bOXJ/view?usp=sharing

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
raw_data = pd.read_csv('Pulse.csv')
raw_data
x1 = raw_data['Hgt']
y = raw_data['Smoke'] 
reg_log = sm.Logit(y,x1,missing='Drop')
results_log = reg_log.fit()
def f(x,b0,b1):
    return np.array(np.exp(b0+x*b1) / (1 + np.exp(b0+x*b1)))
f_sorted = np.sort(f(x1,results_log.params[0],results_log.params[1]))
x_sorted = np.sort(np.array(x1))
plt.scatter(x1,y,color='C0')
plt.xlabel('Hgt', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Smoked', fontsize = 20)
plt.plot(x_sorted,f_sorted,color='C8')
plt.show()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4729         try:
-> 4730             return self._engine.get_value(s, k, tz=getattr(series.dtype, "tz", None))
   4731         except KeyError as e1:
((( Truncated for brevity )))
IndexError: index out of bounds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Intercept** is not added by default in **Statsmodels** regression, but if you need you can include it manually.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()
raw_data = pd.read_csv('Pulse.csv')
raw_data
x1 = raw_data['Hgt']
y = raw_data['Smoke'] 

x1 = sm.add_constant(x1)

reg_log = sm.Logit(y,x1,missing='Drop')
results_log = reg_log.fit()

results_log.summary()

def f(x,b0,b1):
    return np.array(np.exp(b0+x*b1) / (1 + np.exp(b0+x*b1)))
f_sorted = np.sort(f(x1,results_log.params[0],results_log.params[1]))
x_sorted = np.sort(np.array(x1))

plt.scatter(x1['Hgt'],y,color='C0')

plt.xlabel('Hgt', fontsize = 20)
plt.ylabel('Smoked', fontsize = 20)
plt.plot(x_sorted,f_sorted,color='C8')
plt.show()
```

This will also resolve the error as there was no intercept in your initial code.[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20701484/why-do-i-get-only-one-parameter-from-a-statsmodels-ols-fit)

Comment: Thank you so much. By adding the constant, the error was suppressed. I really appreciate it.